# Simple multithreaded fastcgi application always crashing

Tags: c++, multithreading, fastcgi

I'm trying to understand how to properly use FastCGI in a multithreaded environment. However, when compiled, this program always yields an `Internal Server Error` on Apache. I feel as if I'm not familiar enough with FastCGI nor Apache to be able to diagnose my mistake.

A simple single-threaded equivalent of this program worked perfectly fine.

I'm compiling using `g++` with flags `-std=c++11 -lfcgi++ -lfcgi -lpthread`

Below is the code I'm using:

```
#include "fcgio.h"
#include <vector>
#include <ostream>
#include <istream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

std::mutex accept_mutex;

#define THREAD_COUNT (10)

void respond(){
  FCGX_Request request;
  FCGX_InitRequest(&request, 0, 0);
  fcgi_streambuf cout_fcgi_streambuf(request.out);

  std::ostream cout(&cout_fcgi_streambuf);

  for(;;) {
    accept_mutex.lock();
    if (FCGX_Accept_r(&request) < 0)
      break;
    accept_mutex.unlock();
    cout << "Content-type: text/html\r\n"
      << "\r\n"
      << "<html>\n"
      << "  <head>\n"
      << "    <title>Testing!</title>\n"
      << "  </head>\n"
      << "  <body>\n"
      << "    <h1>Hello, World!</h1>\n"
      << "</body>\n"
      << "</html>\n";

    FCGX_Finish_r(&request);
  }

}

int main(){
  FCGX_Init();
  std::vector<std::thread> threads(THREAD_COUNT);
  for(int i = 0 ; i < THREAD_COUNT ; i++)
    threads[i] = std::thread(respond);
  for(auto & x : threads)
    x.join();

}
```

And here is the error I'm finding in the Apache error log:

```
[Wed Mar 25 00:22:10.693368 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 11386:tid 139946920691456] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 10.0.2.2:63490] mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
[Wed Mar 25 00:22:10.693396 2015] [core:error] [pid 11386:tid 139946920691456] [client 10.0.2.2:63490] End of script output before headers: home2.fcgi
[Wed Mar 25 00:22:13.695752 2015] [fcgid:error] [pid 11384:tid 139947238573952] mod_fcgid: process /home/web/web/home2.fcgi(27007) exit(communication error), get unexpected signal 6
```

Comment: What about joining your threads, before exiting `main()`?

Comment: for the sake of exception safety never ever call `lock()` and `unlock()` yourself. Instead use a [`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Oops, the actual code I'm using does join the threads. In my attempt to make a minimal example, I accidentially deleted the `join` calls. I've edited the question, and the problem persists when I `join` my threads, using the edited code in the main post.

Comment: I would also suggest an RAII wrapper around `FCGX_Request` to ensure the request always gets finished.

Comment: And @Mgetz using a `std::lock_guard` did not fix the problem, but I appreciate the help. At this point, I'm just trying to get a minimal functional example up for myself.

Comment: @user2899162 `std::lock_guard` was not an answer or I would have posted it as such. No it was a method of avoiding accidental deadlock.

Comment: Ah, I'm more familiar with mutexes from `C`, so I had thought you were implying that (for some reason) an exception was being thrown by my mutex.

Comment: That said you are getting `SIGABRT` so likely you're getting an exception thrown in `respond()` try doing a [pokemon catch](http://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/) (e.g. `catch(...)`) around the code inside to see what comes in.

Comment: I wrapped all of the code within `respond` in a try catch block, catching `std::exception e`. In the catch block I have `std::ofstream o("myFCGIerr.txt"); o << e.what();` but I can't find a `myFCGIerr.txt` anywhere on my system.

Comment: @user2899162 Add additional information and forth going findings when debugging to your question, to improve it, and getting it bumped and more likely to receive a concise answer, rather than applying additional comments.

Comment: Thank you @Mgetz and πάντα ῥεῖ, I fixed the problem as I wrote it-- I needed to create the `ofstream` inside the for loop. I made a mistake when I tried to make a minimal example, that just happened to have the same errors in Apache as the actual problem I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem as it was presented in my question.

I was making the `ofstream` `cout` before the `for(;;)` loop, when it should be created inside the loop.

This makes sense, as each individual connection has its own stream that should be written to.

-

The problem I have with my larger multithreaded application remains-- in my larger program, I properly instantiate my `ofstream`. When creating my minimal example, I made a mistake that just happened to have the same error logs in Apache. However, my error seems to be unrelated to the question I posted, and now I'm off to hunt for what actually was creating the error in the first place.